# CRUD in embedded web server

Tags: c, rest, embedded, crud, microcontroller

I'm implementing a RESTful web API in an embedded stack which provides a webserver without the REST feature. To be precise, the embedded stack is RTCS which runs on top of the MQX RT operating system, the microcontroller is a Kinetis K60 from Freescale. I'm able to distinguish GET/POST/DELETE/PUT requests and to get the url with the parameters (let's say /this/firstValue/that/secondValue/...).

I use strtok to separate the different elements of the url and take decisions. But my code is just ugly because it's full of strcmp functions and if statements. I also need to check bounds for firstValue and secondValue (which I could do in set/get functions, but 2 functions for each parameter will be repetitve). Moreover I'd like to be able to add parameters without messing around with the decision tree.

I have two questions:

- How would you make the code nice and dry?
- Do you think a REST webservice is appropriate to control my microcontroller over the network? Do you have examples of such things? I'm using a REST webservice because it provides authentication (no secrecy however because I can't setup SSL sockets yet) and I think it's an elegant solution.

  I evaluated some other solutions:
- SNMP (snmpset/snmpget): it worked but setting up the MIBs was a real pain, and since it's SNMPv2 there is still no secrecy.
- telnet server (I have no SSH solution yet): I don't see any advantage/drawback aside that REST will probably be easier to control from the outside, I'm testing it with curl :)
- SOAP Remote Procedure Call (I just don't like it)
- Any other idea ? I need something simple and scalable since there could be multiple targets to control. I have limited resources :s. I would need  secrecy at some point, and I expect to have it when CyaSSL (an embedded ssl implemetation) is ported to MQX. They said it's happening next month so secrecy won't be an issue anymore but if you have other ideas...

--
Emilien

Comment: Why do you want a REST interface on the device itself? Can't you merely write an interface to the device and built a REST interface/API/whatever you call it on a seperate server using Python and some libraries, should save you alot of code and "ugliness".

Comment: Yes why not, but I would still have to do the decision tree by myself,  and when I think about it it's more or less like the SNMP MIB tree...

Answer (score 0):

REST is an architectual pattern, So i guess you mean your server provides HTTP.

A resource is 'any data that can be named'. e.g. an LED on your embedded device could be a URI of '/leds/led3' You could change the data it holds (its state, rgb led? etc) with the standard PUT request, and GET should return its current state.

As for coding it, a generic tree structure maybe wise if memory permits to make path finding as simple as possible. With the data and function pointers (emulating objects) at the leafs

Comment: Yes true it only provides HTTP. I'll try a tree with function pointers at the leafs. I was just curious and wanted a C example of REST webservice, but I could not find one.